# Pass security context when executing query in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, active-directory, ldap, spring-data-mongodb, role-based-access-control

I have a requirement to apply some rules to the collection used for searching and also to the returned docs based on userid and/or role of the caller in mongo db.

I see mongodb provides support to create one or more users internally and use them to fine-grained access policies for resource access.

Normally, roles and userid are created externally in active directory or ldap and we use only one userid when connecting to mongodb from a web app on behalf of all clients.

My query is , Is there a way to map these external userids and roles  to internal userid and what is the mechanism to pass the caller/security context info when executing a command/query in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkout **$redact** operator in Mongo DB. Perhaps, this can help your requirement.
**https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/**

Comment: Thanks. I feel it is one approach which can be leveraged. But, it does put a constraint on the way docs are structured and the also maintained. I do not see any support for using that with spring data mongodb. So, not sure how I can use it.